# How to declare an export type for a set of matching files?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a folder `./plugins`. A plugin has the following interface:

```
type PluginType = () => Promise<(ad: AdType) => TargetingParameterType>;
```

In order to use Flow, I need to import `PluginType` into each plugin script and declare the export type, e.g. this is what I am doing at the moment:

```
import type {
  PluginType
} from './types';

const myPlugin: PluginType = async () => {
  return (ad) => {
    return {};
  };
};

export default myPlugin;
```

The problem with this approach is:

1. It requires to create an intermediate variable (I couldn't find an inline way to annotate `export default` type)
2. It requires that this annotation is included in every `./plugins/*.js` file.

Is there a way to configure Flow to apply `PluginType` type to all files in `./plugins/*.js` folder without needing to add the type declaration to each file?

Comment: Could you explain a bit clearer what you need Flow to do? How does your setup currently look?

Comment: @ahstro I have added more details and improved wording.

Comment: @Gajus: did you have any luck with my solution? If not feel free to edit the question with any problems and I'll try to revise the answer.

Comment: @Aurora0001 You have answered how to annotate a default export in file. However, I have not a way to enforce a particular export type on multiple files using file matching pattern – I think this simply does not exist in Flow type.

Comment: @Gajus I doubt that such a feature exists because it'd be limited to an extremely small use case; the typecast is probably the best you can get if you want to get rid of the intermediate variable. Still, if you think more attention would be helpful, you could always post in the issue tracker or add a bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create project-wide type declarations using ["`.flowconfig`-style" declarations](https://flowtype.org/docs/declarations.html#pointing-your-project-to-declarations). In your `.flowconfig`, add:

```
[libs]

decls/
```

Then create the directory `decls`, and in that create a file called `plugins.js` containing:

```
declare type PluginType = () => Promise<(ad: AdType) => TargetingParameterType>;
```

You may need to include the types that `PluginType` depends on in this file too.

[According to the documentation](https://flowtype.org/docs/declarations.html#declaring-types):

> It is similarly useful to declare types. Like other declarations, type declarations can also be made visible to all modules in a project.

To avoid creating an intermediate variable, you can use the [typecast](https://flowtype.org/docs/syntax.html#typecasts) syntax:

```
export default (async () => {
    return (ad) => {
        return {};
    };
}: PluginType);
```

Comment: This will enable to get rid of the `import type` line, but I will still need to do `const myPlugin: PluginType = () => {}; export default myPlugin` charade. Is there no way to either apply a declared type as the default export to a set of files or alternative syntax to annotate default export?

Comment: I've not tested this, but I've just edited in what I think should fix that.